# SSL certificate : connect to ssl server through a proxy

Tags: ssl, https, proxy

I generate the ssl certificate and save it in the trustStore.
Then i tried to connect to https server without a proxy and it is OK.
When i used a proxy, an exception is generated:

> PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target.

Could you please give a solution

Answer (score 0):

The proxy need to present a certificate trusted by your client, otherwise your client treat that as an attack and stop the connection.

Comment: How to do it  ? i should generate the certificate in the proxy and copy it into  the client's truststore ?

Comment: Yes. The documentation of your proxy should be helpfull